# Why are questions grayed out?

Tags: discussion

I'm curious why some questions appear as grayed out, even though they are not [on hold]. Refer to screenshot below. I'd appreciate if someone could enlighten me.

[image: grayed out question]

Comment: Could you add a link to 1 or more of them please.

Comment: The pages appear correctly: http://bit.ly/2bAQJ0j and http://bit.ly/2bASwT0 but appear grayed out when [viewing tagged questions](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing-cloud?sort=newest&pageSize=50). However, I note that they are only grayed out when I am logged in. If I visit the URL when I am not logged in, they display correctly; refer to [this screenshot](http://digital-logic.s3.amazonaws.com/temp/Screen%20Shot%202016-08-24%20at%204.36.08%20PM.png) when I'm logged in.

Comment: Do you have any **ignored tags**? I use that functionality to monitor the `salesforce-crm` tag, and all such posts are greyed out similar to what you show there.

Comment: @AdrianLarson yes, that was the issue. I had `soap-api` as an ignored tag for some peculiar reason. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! Feel free to add this as an answer and I'll accept it for the benefit of others.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you ignore tags, they they appear as greyed out. I use this feature to highlight `salesforce-crm` tags, which I try to remove as they come in.

You can access it from the home page by clicking the **edit** link next to **Favorite Tags**.

[image: Favorite Tags]

Once you expand that menu, you can see an **Ignored Tags** section.

[image: Ignored Tags]

Notice the **set tag preferences** link. If you follow it, you will find that you can actually choose to completely hide ignored posts instead of greying them out.

[image: Tag Preferences]