# What is meant by question highlighted yellow?

Tags: support

Today, I am suddenly seeing shaded questions as below:

[image]

What does that mean?

Its not voted question/answered question/etc ? (not able to understand - its just random)

Comment: Tweaked your title just a bit to be more clear. Feel free to roll back or change to something else.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is the opposite of [Why are questions grayed out?](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2291/2995)

You have selected a relevant tag in your `Watched Tags` section. In this case, the post is tagged `[soql]`.

Comment: Thanks! I `watched` on some tags yesterday and totally forgot.

Comment: I see - they are in right side pane